# CD player won't play any CDs burned on my mac

Tags: cd-burning

I'm trying to burn some CDs to play on my 1997 CD player but so far no luck
I first burned mp3s on it and then I realized old CD players don't play mp3s
Then I burned .wav files as an audio CD but I used DVD-R because I ran out of CD-R
It still won't work

Using Macbook Pro 2021

What am I doing wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What drive are you using to burn the disks -- an Apple USB SuperDrive? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to burn what is known as a "[Red Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio) CDDA" CD. It doesn't really matter whether or not you understand that term, but that's a 'simple ordinary CD audio' disk.

Many HiFi CD players were not capable of reading more advanced formats such as MP3 CDs or DVD. They simply don't know what they are.

CD Audio is actually burned using AIFF files not WAV, but the difference between these two files types is actually so small that your computer will just adjust the format on the fly as it burns the CD, so you won't have to make any special preparation for that.

All you should need is your folder full of WAV files, numbered if you want a specific play order, as it will burn them alphabetically. Once burned the names are discarded, as CDDA contains no track information.

Set your software to burn a CD Audio disk & use an actual CD, not a DVD.

If you're using iTunes/Apple Music, then set up like this…

[image]

Note the burn speed is set very low. This is an old trick to get better results on older CD players with less tolerance of burn errors. A 2-second gap was the old default standard for audio CDs. you can set this how you wish.
I've not done this in a long time, but I think iTunes will up-convert on the fly even if your input tracks are AAC or MP3, so it will automatically handle any format as it burns the CD, so long as you set it as above.
Using Sound Check is up to you [to balance the audio levels between tracks], but don't use CD Text if you want playback on such an old player.

Answer (score 0):

It was / is common that CDs or DVDs would work in some drives and not others.

This was mainly down to the tolerances of head position etc. one drive at the max and the other at the min.

First test is does the CD or DVD work in the drive that wrote it? If it does then the data format etc is fine.

Then test the CD in other drives, if it works there then it is down to the tolerances.

I have 3 drives capable of writing CDs and 1 does not get used for writing for that reason.

Comment: It's not particularly surprising that a 90s CD player wouldn't be able to handle DVDs. If it can't handle mp3, then it's not any kind of 'computer' drive, it's just an audio player, red book & red book only.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to burn mp3 files onto a CD. The burning process converts the audio into the AIFF format as it happens.

What matters is the type of disk and the format that the disk is burnt with.

A DVD disk won't work on a standard CD player.